# How to remove individual attributes within cluster plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis

I would like a fairly plain, publication-quality cluster plot. I have created the plot and removed the title, legend and adjusted the axis titles, with the script provided. However, I would also like to remove all of the individual row labels 'attributes' that are my sample ID's within each of the two cluster's e.g. CLR45, HTR132. Is this possible?   [image: Image Cluster Plot]

```
fviz_cluster(k2, data = Chem)+ theme(legend.position = "none")+labs(title = "") +  theme(
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = unit(c(3, 0, 0, 0), "mm")),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = unit(c(0, 3, 0, 0), "mm")))

dput(head(Chem,50))
structure(c(0.147411356827536, -0.94833184269442, -0.236098761737746, 
-0.156408346996621, -1.07782876612066, 0.15737266025443, -0.85369947703763, 
-0.684357344128487, -0.744125156240499, -0.166369650423515, 1.06883177595158, 
-1.72531338325188, -1.16249983257523, -0.908486633211519, -1.30693870691714, 
-1.04296420835121, 0.336676092365792, -0.45026675161856, -0.455247403332007, 
-0.935222767283235, -0.798912316639064, 0.185622913832727, -0.345812539076084, 
0.264855107585394, -0.649213869051943, -0.745838498773852, -0.952615203252478, 
0.510998876988382, 1.40751604176986, -0.749105803729271, 0.222121124079889, 
0.146973059409158, -0.25104071265341, -0.176330949625734, -0.734163852813605, 
1.1584834941196, 0.869605741211104, 0.202198517226101, 0.301811538821014, 
-0.0567953296263845, -0.669415393212821, -0.191272904766074, 
-0.71922190189794, 0.222121124079889, -0.51999586293279, -0.231118110024299, 
0.5608053856735, -0.285905270422864, -0.614628232814256, 0.0378370402550813, 
1.21148988263212, -0.722729092058211, 0.938866964062205, 1.29275958711264, 
1.23956487191698, 1.86977449177269, 1.84761002727152, 2.09068032585176, 
0.430561900436177, -0.339283848035902, 3.19668712695198, -0.305298335931744, 
-0.0186379222283033, 3.76926913851535, -0.987963856121806, 0.356680351444172, 
3.44123505721924, 0.255462628028634, -1.00052371956831, -0.425184448439876, 
-0.0334142322231424, -0.313100227585446, -1.0460909046001, 0.779075947446034, 
-1.04523092273039, -0.432924280356334, -0.788096532267007, 0.836910424803157, 
0.471935569011041, -0.841678386878241, 3.4264587472244, 0.770476135624245, 
1.97394747659788, 0.635952609659098, -0.86162640581326, -0.502562073822641, 
0.695796664499772, -0.659190958982183, 0.126169915328244, -0.127243800150166, 
-0.945851372685624, -0.589742302104659, -0.506994966919312, -0.665840298627189, 
-0.90004481199628, -0.82320799963024, -0.566839021759986, -0.759669866554213, 
-0.980575700633291, 0.208917251495781, -1.23882313589815, -0.816688277463794, 
0.346387764578252, 0.524062438145321, 1.46662027130976, -0.917496601945682, 
1.0860688452788, 2.10423292402831, 0.254400170526879, -0.804087236829436, 
-0.843150462529107, -0.300045614716482, 0.672754716385498, -0.9527795153661, 
-0.622632253058524, 0.0175006072532231, 0.578246912369032, 1.71864108103204, 
-1.24512365636358, 2.67546329317061, -1.0435070073998, -1.24421134102627, 
1.42382713735224, 2.28432699595981, 0.587773297320356, 0.00106885031820219, 
0.211304610661984, -0.589869547527789, 0.65259305148912, 0.00867987889811877, 
-1.54754862951275, 0.235750629237659, -0.331548216154132, 1.18561706626058, 
-0.368091233667634, -1.09769148192, -1.03846659132395, -0.70957943281297, 
-0.316426967333605, -1.05358783984799, -1.19471949412263, -0.788965988305396, 
0.663933988919855, 0.346387764578252, 0.137210492538405, 0.146031220893509, 
-0.456298517515165, -0.534424969210994, 0.450976402525343, 0.193915175837746, 
1.53543257619906, -0.518118831649496, -0.16974850422888, 0.380309904408398, 
-0.518118831649496, -0.114742659464473, 3.20394309995186, 1.0953858473389, 
0.893697766122234, 0.710344953491444, -0.316430750432833, 0.453651027510375, 
-0.444777708547519, 1.99381459314849, -0.664801077853449, 1.99381459314849, 
0.343639347733259, 0.105280700089759, -0.811483324057402, 3.43885470777859, 
-0.829818602394972, 0.948923628687728, -1.17727227024187, 0.507850124084635, 
-0.054162900383238, 0.0383202589981529, -0.111075611598317, 0.215292379866875, 
-0.243089627330857, -0.609795233089042, -0.499783553311926, -0.367182807190326, 
-0.719806922617856, 0.105280700089759, -0.353101307107973, 0.728680241580711, 
-0.848153880732542, -0.994836126936495, -1.26986533125513, -0.976500848598925, 
0.398645192497665, -1.01317140527406, 0.123615978427329, -0.774812757630565, 
-1.08651252837604, -0.646465799515879, -0.536454109987066, -0.829818602394972, 
0.508656872274782, -0.518118831649496, 0.675002376238412, -0.0617082448613822, 
-0.668996727923662, -1.60481832778947, -0.71877447345135, 0.625224632383091, 
-1.78899598306442, -0.793441090906698, -1.09210755738336, 1.32211305639179, 
-1.96321808990278, -1.51521838684306, 0.00549171084843096, -2.9911285157337, 
0.276780418706376, -2.1225068715777, -1.56499613237074, -0.683930051414732, 
0.271802645324263, 0.398636337390084, -0.270774772063992, 0.662607717406351, 
1.26287754043467, -0.00695272427921605, 0.459290519580567, -0.0828886740640689, 
-0.779976209944577, 0.525669143000081, 1.64566839646848, -0.527130156430866, 
-1.99806251026703, 0.852509813910332, -1.05477425032805, 0.0726916665582448, 
0.177224929323366, 0.824335611149109, -0.444996877229983, -0.0218860477702858, 
-1.2713074392762, -0.270774772063992, -0.0467749213703124, 0.625224632383091, 
-0.569441240213019, 0.722291233402677, 0.401224781689411, 0.127447185468045, 
0.80442451260356, -0.594330112140679, 0.824335611149109, 0.276780418706376
), .Dim = c(50L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("CLR16", "CLR36", "CLR52", 
"CLR56", "CLR20", "CLR22", "CLR11", "CLR14", "CLR17", "CLR33", 
"CLR41", "CLR43", "CLR50", "CLR32", "CLR35", "CLR37", "CLR45", 
"CLR48", "CLR49", "CLR5", "CLR55", "CLR58", "CLR59", "CLR6", 
"CLR60", "CLR61", "CLR62", "CLR65", "CLR66", "CLR67", "CLR68", 
"CLR7", "GGR70", "GGR77", "GGR71", "GGR69", "GGR72", "GGR73", 
"GGR74", "GGR75", "GGR76", "GGR78", "GGR79", "GGR80", "GGR81", 
"GGR83", "GGR84", "GGR85", "GGR87", "GGR89"), c("X88Sr_umol_molCa", 
"X138Ba_umol_molCa", "X25Mg_umol_molCa", "X55Mn_umol_molCa", 
"X7Li_umol_molCa")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `labelsize = 0` as shown in the following code

```
library("factoextra")

# Data preparation
data("iris")
head(iris)
# Remove species column (5) and scale the data
iris.scaled <- scale(iris[, -5])

# K-means clustering
km.res <- kmeans(iris.scaled, 3, nstart = 25)

# Visualize kmeans clustering
fviz_cluster(km.res, iris[, -5], labelsize = 0) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") + labs(title = "") +  
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = unit(c(3, 0, 0, 0), "mm")),
  axis.title.y = element_text(margin = unit(c(0, 3, 0, 0), "mm")))
```

[image]

To remove all the little geometric shapes use `geom = NULL` like

```
fviz_cluster(km.res, iris[, -5], geom = NULL, labelsize = 0) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") + labs(title = "") +  
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = unit(c(3, 0, 0, 0), "mm")),
  axis.title.y = element_text(margin = unit(c(0, 3, 0, 0), "mm")))
```

[image]
To remove cluster centers use `show.clust.cent = F`

```
fviz_cluster(km.res, iris[, -5], geom = NULL, labelsize = 0, show.clust.cent = F) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") + labs(title = "") +  
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = unit(c(3, 0, 0, 0), "mm")),
  axis.title.y = element_text(margin = unit(c(0, 3, 0, 0), "mm")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou. Is it possible to remove all of the little geometric shapes as well so the cluster's are just a solid colour. I intend to include a table of the proportions of each of my locations that fall into the clusters

Comment: fviz_cluster(k2, data = Chem), labelsize = 0) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")+labs(title = "") +  theme(
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = unit(c(3, 0, 0, 0), "mm")),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = unit(c(0, 3, 0, 0), "mm")))

Comment: Have I done this wrong because I got an error : Error: unexpected ',' in "fviz_cluster(k2, data = Chem),"

Comment: Can you provide your data as `dput(Chem)`?

Comment: This worked: fviz_cluster(k2, data = Chem, geom = NULL, labelsize = 0) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")+labs(title = "") +  theme(
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = unit(c(3, 0, 0, 0), "mm")),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = unit(c(0, 3, 0, 0), "mm")))

Comment: That worked except that, and this is being pedantic, but if you look closely in the pink cluster there is one small dot left over. Do you know why this would remain?

Comment: dput(Chem)fviz_cluster(k2, data = Chem, geom = NULL, labelsize = 0) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")+labs(title = "") +  theme(
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = unit(c(3, 0, 0, 0), "mm")),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = unit(c(0, 3, 0, 0), "mm")))

Comment: Is this how I provide my data?

Comment: Actually, I just noticed your 'clean' cluster plot has the dot remaining as well in the pink cluster

Comment: My data is very long is there a way to provide a reduced data set? Also I can't see the check box I am supposed to tick to accept the answer. Sorry I'm a new to this

Comment: Use `dput(head(Chem, 50)`. Don't understand `I can't see the check box`, Can you show the desired output by editing the question? It was not part of your initial question.

Comment: To accept an answer:

Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: Below the inverted triangle (upvote downvote), click on this √ to accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay Bappa Das. I have just edited my initial question with the output from dput(head(Chem,50)